# Change direction of slide transition animation to left

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

When I open a specific view, I want to change the direction of the slide animation to --> from right to left instead of the default direction (left to right).

I found a solution to change the animation transition. Although this is a flip animation and I want to change the direction of the default slide animation of a navigation controller.

```
var screen = new Screen();
NavigationController.PushViewController(screen, false);

UIView.BeginAnimations(null,IntPtr.Zero);
UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.75);
UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromLeft , NavigationController.View,true); // <-- Change the animation
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

Note: I am using MonoTouch/C#

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, again I got nothing in MonoTouch/C#, but I have implemented the same behavior in ObjC, and it emulates the sliding perfectly. In this case it is used to emulate the sliding back behavior when getting to a view with a tabbar. Maybe it is helpful:

```
- (void)hitBack
{
    // Get the views.
    UIView * fromView = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = ((UIViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view;

    // Get the size of the view area.
    CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

    // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

    // Position it off screen.
    toView.frame = CGRectMake( -320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:
     ^{
         // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
         fromView.frame =CGRectMake( 320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
         toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (finished)
         {
             // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
             [fromView removeFromSuperview];

             //change tab
             self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
         }
     }];
}
```

In C#:

```
void HitBack ()
{
    // Get the views.
    var fromView = tabBarController.SelectedViewController.View;
    var toView = tabBarController.ViewControllers [0].View;

    // Get the size of the view area.
    var viewSize = fromView.Frame;

    // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
    fromView.Superview.AddSubview (toView);

    // Position it off screen.
    toView.Frame = new RectangleF ( -320 , viewSize.Y, 320, viewSize.Height);

    UIView.Animate (0.4, () => { animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:
         // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
         fromView.Frame = new RectangleF ( 320 , viewSize.Y, 320, viewSize.Height);
         toView.Frame =new RectangleF (0, viewSize.Y, 320, viewSize.Height);
     }, (bool finished) => {
         if (finished){
             // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
             fromView.RemoveFromSuperview ();

             //change tab
             tabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;
         });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want below.  This is a transition from a tab view.  Hope it will help out some people:

```
protected void HandleLeftSwipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    if (this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex != 4) {
        UIView fromView = this.TabBarController.SelectedViewController.View;
        UIView toView = this.TabBarController.ViewControllers[this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex+1].View;

        // Get the size of the view area.
        var viewSize = fromView.Frame;

        // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
        fromView.Superview.AddSubview (toView);

        var minAlpha = -320.0;
        var maxAlpha = 320.0;
        var midAlpha =0.0;
        // Position it off screen.
        toView.Frame = new CGRect ( maxAlpha , viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
        UIView.Animate (.3,.1, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut ,
            () => { 
                fromView.Frame = new CGRect ( minAlpha , viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
                toView.Frame =new CGRect (midAlpha, viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
            },
            () => {
                fromView.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex + 1;
            }
        );
    }
}

protected void HandleRightSwipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    if (this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex != 0) {
        UIView fromView = this.TabBarController.SelectedViewController.View;
        UIView toView = this.TabBarController.ViewControllers[this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex-1].View;

        // Get the size of the view area.
        var viewSize = fromView.Frame;

        // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
        fromView.Superview.AddSubview (toView);

        var minAlpha = -320.0;
        var maxAlpha = 320.0;
        var midAlpha =0.0;
        // Position it off screen.
        toView.Frame = new CGRect ( minAlpha , viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
        UIView.Animate (.3,.1, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut ,
            () => { 
                fromView.Frame = new CGRect ( maxAlpha , viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
                toView.Frame =new CGRect (midAlpha, viewSize.Y, maxAlpha, viewSize.Height);
            },
            () => {
                fromView.RemoveFromSuperview ();
                this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex = this.TabBarController.SelectedIndex - 1;
            }
        );
    }
}
```